# Numpy loadtxt error with double slashes in file path and odd characters

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I'm using python(x,y) and I'm having trouble using the numpy loadtxt function where previously it worked fine in linux. The code looks like this:

```
 from numpy import loadtxt    
 values=loadtxt("C:\Users\My_username\path\to\txt\file",float)
```

I've checked that the path is correct(don't think I need to use any escape characters), and the file is fine. It was originally a linux file which i converted to a windows file but it looks fine. Don't know why the error is inserting double backslashes and "x08"

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename:
    'C:\\Users\\Michael\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\university\third_year\\uni_work\\labs\x08andgap_spectro\x08andgap_spectro_GaAs_1nm\x08andgap_GaAs_v_vs_lambda_1nm.txt'
```

Had to copy that error from cmd since ipython dont let you select text and copy like a human. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's just from the copy and pasting from the cmd. I couldn't get it to indent properly on the input editor on this page. This error is produced by both the cmd and ipython commandline.

Comment: OK, does it match your error now?

Comment: Yes, but there is no space after Skydrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my usual tricks aren't working.  Try using `os.path` and forward slashes

```
import os
import numpy as np

fname = os.path.normpath('C:/Users/Michael/SkyDrive/Documents/university/third_year/uni_work/labs/bandgap_spectro/bandgap_spectro_GaAs_1nm/bandgap_GaAs_v_vs_lambda_1nm.txt')
np.loadtxt(fname, float)
```

---

Try this:

```
loadtxt(ur'C:\Users\Michael\SkyDrive\Documents\university\third_year\uni_work\labs\bandgap_spectro\bandgap_spectro_GaAs_1nm\bandgap_GaAs_v_vs_lambda_1nm.txt', float)
```

With the `ur` in front of your filename.

The `r` prefix will tell python that the string is *raw* and escapes should be ignored.  In fact, it inserts the double backslash automatically:

```
In [132]: r'C:\Users\Michael\SkyDrive\Documents\university\third_year\uni_work\labs\bandgap_spectro\bandgap_spectro_GaAs_1nm\bandgap_GaAs_v_vs_lambda_1nm.txt'
Out[132]: 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\university\\third_year\\uni_work\\labs\\bandgap_spectro\\bandgap_spectro_GaAs_1nm\\bandgap_GaAs_v_vs_lambda_1nm.txt'
```

The `u` tells it to use unicode.

And the `x08` comes from a `\b`:

```
In [133]: '\b'
Out[133]: '\x08'
```

which is the backspace character.

Comment: That gets rid of the "x08" but the error still has the double slashes in it.

Comment: I then get the error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'rawunicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3:truncated \uXXXX

Comment: Getting a "No such file or directory" error now. I am copying and pasting the full path from the file's properties dilogue then just changing the slashes. If it helps, im using the ipython "execfile" to run the program but it does this in cmd too.

Comment: Sorry, The above are the standard ways to handle file names to my knowledge.  To continue, you can try testing similar filenames with just `open(fname)` (not `loadtxt`) and try using relative paths instead of full paths, to see if you can find a pattern.  Relative paths can be used as long as the full path would begin with whatever `os.getcwd()` returns.  Also, see if the file shows up with `os.listdir()`.

Comment: It's working now. os.listdir showed that the files were named filename.txt.txt so I removed that extra extension, and I'm also back to using just loadtxt(r"C:\path\to\file",float). Thanks.